# JavaScript minus calculation between two variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically I am trying to compare if the coordinates passing in match the items in an array list. So I have an array called busList with array item in this format:

```
27794.27939,43930.90485
```

And then I am trying to loop thru the array to compare the coordinates that I passed in. The coordinates that I passed in are two variables: coordx and coordy.

```
for(var i = 0; i < busList.length; i++){
    var parts = busList[i].split(",");
    buslocX = parts[0];
    buslocY = parts[1];

    if((coordx - buslocX < 0.0050) && (coordy - buslocY < 0.0050)){
        console.log(coordx - buslocX);
    }
}
```

If the coordx - the x coordinates in the array is less than 0.0050 and as well as the y, then I will perform something else. With these codes, I am trying to print the result of the minus, but I did not get anything in the console.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

In a short word, I am trying to check if coordx,coordy matches any items inside the array. But there will be slight difference like 0.0050 for the coordx,coordy with the array items. For example, I got a list of coordinates for array:

```
27794.27939,43930.90485
27539.43390,43422.26042
```

And the coordx I passed in is 27794.27920 and coordy is 43930.90480. Because both of the coordx and coordy is less than 0.0050 than first item in array, then I will perform something else.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to convert `buslocX` and `buslocY` to [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) type?

```
buslocX = parseFloat(parts[0]);
buslocY = parseFloat(parts[1]);
```

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method converts *string* to array of *strings* and in that case bahaviour of calculations may be unexpected.

Comment: Can you help me check my further explanation part? Because I think my logic is wrong right from the start.

Comment: @Denise it works well for me. http://jsfiddle.net/s1xky4yu/1/ in console I get `-0.0001899999988381751`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var parts = busList[i].split(".");
```

instead

```
var parts = busList[i].split(",");
```

Comment: The busList coordinates are in the further explanation part. Can you help me check with it? Because I think my logic was wrong.